# How to display incorrect answers in example below

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Below I have 4 database tables, Session, Question, Answer and Option_Type.

**Session Table:**

```
SessionId  SessionName
1          AAA
```

**Question Table:**

```
SessionId   QuestionId  QuestionContent       OptionId
1           1           What is 1+1 and 4+4   2
1           2           Does 2+2 = 4          26
1           3           What is 3+3 and 5+5   3
```

**Answer Table:**

```
AnswerId  SessionId QuestionId  Answer
1         1         1           B
2         1         1           C
3         1         2           Yes
4         1         3           A
5         1         3           C
```

**Option_Type**

```
OptionId OptionType
1        A-C
2        A-D
3        A-E
4        A-F

.... goes up to 24 where it goes up to A-Z

25       True or False
26       Yes or No
```

Now in a jsfiddle here I have created a demo html table which you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WHUkh/6/)

Now if you have a good look at the html table, you will realise that what I am trying to do is display the incorrect answers under the "Incorrect Answer" column.

So what I want to do is that for example for Question 1, if you look in the database table, the "OptionId" for Question 1 is 2, which means if you look up "OptionId" under the "Option_Type" table that "OptionType" for this OptionId is "A-D". So the options are "A", "B", "C" and "D". The answers for Question 1 are "B" and "C". So I don't want to display these answers in the table as they are correct but I want to display the other options "A" and "D" as that they are incorrect.

Does this make sense? My question is virtually how can I not show the correct answers under the "Incorrect Answer" column but instead show the other options under this column per question in the code below:

```
   $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
   FROM Session s 
   INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
   JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
   WHERE s.SessionName = ?
   ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
   ";

   // prepare query
   $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
   // You only need to call bind_param once
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
   // execute query
   $stmt->execute(); 


       // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionContent = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();
    $searchMarks = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array

   // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
   $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbQuestionMarks);
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
        $searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
        $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
        $searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
      } 

?>      

</head>

<body>

<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

<?php 

echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
      <tr>
      <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
      <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
      <th class='answerth'>Incorrect Answer</th>
      <th class='answermarksth'>Penalty per Incorrect Answer</th>
      </tr>\n";
$previous_question_id = null;
$rowspans = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {

    // removed logic, not necessary to set empty strings if you're skipping them

    echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;

    if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
        echo '<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">';
    echo $searchAnswer[$key];
    echo '</td>' ;
    echo '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" /></td>' . PHP_EOL;

    // moved this to the end
    if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
        $previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
    }
}
        echo '</tr>';
        echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

        ?>

</form>
```

At the moment the code above is showing the correct answers under the "Incorrect Answers" column, not the incorrect answers.

Comment: Please comment to me on the reason for the down mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a table of potential options:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE Answer_Options (Answer VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

   INSERT INTO  Answer_Options VALUES
     ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'),
     ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'),
     ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z'),

     ('True'), ('False'),
     ('Yes'),  ('No')
   ;
   ```
2. Create a table that associates `Option_Type` records with these options:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE OptionType_Options (
     OptionId TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     Answer   VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (OptionId) REFERENCES Option_Type    (OptionId),
     FOREIGN KEY (Answer  ) REFERENCES Answer_Options (Answer  )
   );

   INSERT INTO OptionType_Options (OptionId, Answer)
     SELECT o.OptionId, a.Answer
     FROM Answer_Options a JOIN Option_Type o ON (
            o.OptionType LIKE '_-_' AND
            CHAR_LENGTH(a.Answer) = 1 AND
            a.Answer BETWEEN  LEFT(o.OptionType, 1)
                         AND RIGHT(o.OptionType, 1)
          ) OR (
            o.OptionType LIKE '% or %' AND
            a.Answer IN (
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(o.OptionType, ' or ',  1),
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(o.OptionType, ' or ', -1)
            )
          )
   ;
   ```
3. Define the `Answer.Answer` column as a foreign key into this new table.

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE Answer ADD FOREIGN KEY (Answer) REFERENCES Answer_Options (Answer);
   ```
4. Optionally delete from `Option_Type` the now superfluous `OptionType` column (however it might be useful to retain as human-readable "name/comment" type metadata):

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE Option_Type DROP COLUMN OptionType;
   ```

   If so desired, one can still obtain the previous table with:

   ```sql
   SELECT   t.*,
            CONCAT_WS(
              IF(COUNT(*) > 2, '-', ' or '),
              MIN(o.Answer),
              MAX(o.Answer)
            ) AS OptionType
   FROM     Option_Type t JOIN OptionType_Options o USING (OptionId)
   GROUP BY OptionId
   ```
5. Now one can perform an outer join between the possible answers and the correct ones, determining incorrect answers from those outside of the intersection:

   ```sql
   SELECT      Question.*,
               GROUP_CONCAT(o.Answer)                   AS  Possible_Answers,
               GROUP_CONCAT(a.Answer)                   AS   Correct_Answers,
               GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(o.Answer, a.Answer)) AS Incorrect_Answers
   FROM        OptionType_Options o JOIN Question USING (OptionId)
     LEFT JOIN Answer a USING (SessionId, QuestionId, Answer)
   GROUP BY    QuestionId
   ```

   See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40784/1/0).
6. To create your desired output:

   ```php
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('
     SELECT      s.SessionId,  s.SessionName,
                 q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, q.QuestionMarks,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(o.Answer ORDER BY o.Answer SEPARATOR 0x1e),
                 COUNT(*)
     FROM        OptionType_Options o
            JOIN Question q USING ( OptionId)
            JOIN Session  s USING (SessionId)
       LEFT JOIN Answer   a USING (SessionId, QuestionId, Answer)
     WHERE       s.SessionName = ? -- SessionId would be better
             AND a.Answer IS NULL
     GROUP BY    s.SessionId, q.QuestionId
     ORDER BY    q.QuestionId
   ') or die($mysqli->error);
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $assessment) or die($stmt->error);
   $stmt->execute() or die ($stmt->error); 

   if (!$stmt->num_rows) die ('No results.');

   echo '
   <form id="QandA" method="post">
     <table border="1" id="markstbl">
       <tr>
         <th class="questionth">Question No.</th>
         <th class="questionth">Question</th>
         <th class="answerth">Incorrect Answer</th>
         <th class="answermarksth">Penalty per Incorrect Answer</th>
       </tr>
   ';

   $stmt->bind_result(
     $dbSessionId,  $dbSessionName,
     $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbQuestionMarks
     $dbAnswers,    $rowspan
   );

   while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     echo 
       '<tr class="questiontd">', PHP_EOL,
         '<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="',$rowspan,'">',
           htmlspecialchars($dbQuestionId),
         '</td>', PHP_EOL,
         '<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="'.$rowspan.'">',
           htmlspecialchars($dbQuestionContent),
         '</td>', PHP_EOL
       ;

       $first = true;
       foreach (explode(chr(0x1e), $dbAnswers) as $dbAnswer) {
         if (!$first) echo
       '<tr class="questiontd">', PHP_EOL;

         echo
         '<td class="answertd">',htmlspecialchars($dbAnswer),'</td>',
         '<td class="answermarkstd"><input',
           ' class="individualMarks"',
           ' name="answerMarks[',$dbAnswer,']"',
           ' id="individualtext"',
           ' type="text"',
         '/></td>', PHP_EOL,
       '</tr>';

         $first = false;
       }
   }

   echo '
       </table>
     </form>
   ';
   ```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer, Thank You so, so much